# metrics on strength of linear relation

Tags: correlation, linear

I would like to know what are the available metrics to describe the strength of linear correlation between two variables, `spearman` or `pearson` correlation might not be good choices.

For example, *Y {Y1, ..., Yn}* are the observed value for `n {1, ..., n}` objects, which are the golden standard value. *A, B* are **predicted value by two differetn algorithms** for the same n objects, *{A1, ..., An}, {B1, ..., Bn}.* We would like to know **which algorithm is better in predicting Y**, and currently condsider to use **the linear correlation between *Y* and *A/B* as the judegment**.

The scatter plots between `Y ~ A` and `Y ~ B` are shown in figure 1 and 2, respectively. The linear correlation formular, pvalue of coefficient in linear correlation (x) and correlation coefficient (`spearman`) are shown in the plots as well.

From my point of value, *A* in figure 1 is better correlated with *Y* as there is no branch, although the variance is larger. However, both pvalue of lm and spearman correlation suggest the correlation between *B* and *Y* is stronger.

What other metrics/methods I could use to describe the **linear relation** between A/B and Y? or more broadly **which approaches should be used to select the better algorithms behind A/B?**

[image: scatter plots]

Comment: Spearman correlation doesn't measure linear correlation. Among the lot of possible measures of correlation, most of them won't measure linear correlation, either.

Comment: How do you compute P ? and plots are geared to different origins  and X - axis  in two cases is different?

Comment: Talking of correlation aswell as as linear ?

Comment: Your judgement that the relationship is less linear the in second plot seems to be based on it being obvious in the second plot, that a non-linear relationship would give a much better fit. But this is not obvious for the first.. One way of automating this judgement would be to fit both OLS regression and a locally linear regression to the data and to look at the ratio in their mean squared errors.

Comment: @Pere, I modified the question description to emphasize that I want measurements of "linear correlation".

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar x1 (A), x2 (B) are predicted value by two approaches, that's why they are different. P is the pvalue of coefficient of x, returned by lm. We would like to select a better algorithm basing on linear relation.

Comment: @CloseToC Fitting a local linear regression is nice idea. I have modified the problem description, could you think other ways to judge which algorithm generated A/B is better?

Comment: you have diferent gradation of base line for two figures.  no description of  X axis and y axis.  P  is not clear to me . What is being measured/tested ?

Comment: P is the pvalue of b1 in linear regression y ~ b0 + b1x, where y is Y, and x could be A or B. A and B are different as they are predicted value, and compared to Y, which is the true value.

Comment: I am not aware of the ground for different scaling for Y -axis in Two figures.

Comment: I can n't make out about C' fitting. Do you want to check two algorithms based on single dataset and in terms of linear Versus non-linear.